# pyobjc & EventKit: trouble saving event (EKErrorDomain Code=11)

Tags: eventkit, pyobjc, ekevent, ekeventstore

I'm trying to save an event using pyobjc, but I get an EKErrorDomain Code 11 ("That event does not belong to that event store").

Here's what I have so far:

```
ek_store = EKEventStore.alloc().initWithAccessToEntityTypes_(0)
print(f'{ek_store=}')

my_cal_identifier = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
my_calendar = ek_store.calendarWithIdentifier_(my_cal_identifier)
print(f'{my_calendar.eventStore()=}')  # obviously ek_store

event = EKEvent.alloc().init()
event.setEventStore_(ek_store)
print(f'{event.eventStore()=}')  # ek_store, of course

event.setStartDate_(my_startDate)  # NSDate, declared earlier
event.setEndDate_(my_endDate)  # NSDate, declared earlier
event.setCalendar_(my_calendar)
event.setTitle_('My new event')

ek_store.saveEvent_span_error_(
    event, 0, None
)  # this throws the EKErrorDomain error
```

I'm utterly confused by the error message: the calendar as well as the event have the right event store set (I have only one defined anyway). What does this error mean in this context?

What am I missing?

In the documentation, it says "Create a new event with the `init(eventStore:)` method of the EKEvent class."

So maybe my problem stems from not understanding how to correctly create a new event with pyobjc (init does not allow arguments, so how can I pass on the event store?).

Answer (score 0):

You should create the Event using the `eventWithEventStore_` method, e.g.:

```py
event = EKEvent.eventWithEventStore_(ek_store)
```

With that change the code works for me (well after making sure the interpreter had access to the calendar using `ek_store.requestAccessToEntityType_completion_`).

Using `setEventStore_` probably doesn't work because it is not a documented API in Apple's documentation.